# Java program to jumble a string not working

Tags: java, random

```
// java program to jumble a string
import java.util.*;
public class jumble
{
     public static void main()
     {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         String a ;
         System.out.println("Enter a word");
         a = s.nextLine();
         int length = a.length();
         Random r = new Random();
         String newstring = "" ;

         int array[] = new int[length];
         List l = Arrays.asList(array);
         int i = 1 ; 
         int arpos = 0 ; 
         while(i<= length)
         {
             int random = r.nextInt(length);
             if(!(l.contains(random)))
             {
                 newstring = newstring + a.charAt(random) ;
                 array[arpos] = random ;
                 l = Arrays.asList(array);
                 arpos ++ ;
                 i++ ;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(newstring); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly does not work?

Comment: There's a chance that you're code will run into infinite loop. Pay attention to where you're incrementing `i`.

Answer (score 1):

there is no `main method`  run in your class to run the class.your main method is not a valid main method it just a method named main.you can call it in main method or add `string arg[]` to parameter list.probably you forget to add arguments

change

```
public static void main()
```

to

```
public static void main(String arg[])
```

finally code class should be :

```
import java.util.*;
public class jumble
{
     public static void main(String arg[])//main method
     {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         String a ;
         System.out.println("Enter a word");
         a = s.nextLine();
         int length = a.length();
         Random r = new Random();
         String newstring = "" ;

         int array[] = new int[length];
         List l = Arrays.asList(array);
         int i = 1 ; 
         int arpos = 0 ; 
         while(i<= length)
         {
             int random = r.nextInt(length);
             if(!(l.contains(random)))
             {
                 newstring = newstring + a.charAt(random) ;
                 array[arpos] = random ;
                 l = Arrays.asList(array);
                 arpos ++ ;
                 i++ ;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(newstring);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be like this code, because it just fixes the most obvious problem, but leaves other bugs in there.

Comment: @Tom i don't even understand about what you are taking

Comment: @Tom i don't .it should be done by op because i don't want to jumble a string and i guess op can't run the program because there isn't a main method probably missing